# SSL certificate issue: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am getting below issue

SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I already set in my php.ini & also check this file is exits in mentioned path.

```
curl.cainfo = "D:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

Still i am getting same issue.

Can you guys suggest me what is the issue or something missing ?

Thanks in Advance!

Viku V.

Comment: where did you get cacert.pem from?

Comment: I got this from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem